# how to overwrite satchmo default admin url to own one?

Tags: django, url, admin, overwrite, satchmo

i want to overwrite the default admin url in satchmo project. Now i have

www.example.com/admin/ But i need to have www.example.com/Myadmin/.

Here i have some limitations, can not change the satchmo orignal code.
I have to do it in my own satchmo project.

please help...

thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a matter of revising your admin entry in urls.py. Where you currently (I assume) have:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

change it to:

```
(r'^Myadmin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```